# Custom Back Button in NavigationGroup (Titanium Mobile)

Tags: ios, navigation, back, titanium-mobile

Developing in Titanium Mobile (latest SDK)

I have a navigationGroup with navBarHidden set to true. Within my windows, I have custom Back and Next buttons. The next button is obviously a cake walk, as it just opens a new window within the navigation group.

My question is the back button. How can I give my back button the same functionality as the default back button which iOS automatically adds to a navigationGroup?

Comment: can't your 'back' button just close the window? That should remove the window from your navigationGroup stack.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are hiding your navbar?

you declare a navigation group like this:

```
  var nav = Titanium.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
  window: win1 //win1 is window defined above

 });
```

Now suppose you have win2(another window) on which you navigate.
so while opening that win2 just do like this

```
nav.open(win2,{animated:true});
```

by doing this the titanium will automatically add a back button on the top.

**OR**

you can do like this if you dont want that automatic back button

```
 var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
 var b = Titanium.UI.createButton({title:'Back'});
 win.leftNavButton = b;
    b.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
       alert('I was clicked'); // to confirm its being called
    // do the stuff here
    win.close();
  });
```

Comment: I have a custom back button within the main UI. win.close(), while it closes the window, doesn't bring back the previous window, nor does the right to left animation exist, like a standard back button.

Comment: before closing that window i.e before using win.close() you have to load your screen..